# Applying request values to entity bean loaded with id from inputHidden before other fields

Tags: jsf, viewparams, omnifaces

I have a facelet template with:

```
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{homeBean.id}" />
</f:metadata>                

<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{homeBean.id}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{homeBean.user.firstName}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{homeBean.onSave()}" />
</h:form>
```

and a request scoped bean with:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class HomeBean {
    private Integer id;
    private User user;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
      System.out.println("setId called");
      user = // code for loading User entity bean with supplied id
    }

    // other accessors for id and user
}
```

Initial page load works well, entity is loaded and displayed in a form, inputHidden is set to entity id. Problem is that submit throws:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException - Target unreachable, base expression '. user' resolved to null
```

probably because getUser is called before setId. How can I solve this? I really would like to have a request scoped bean, I know that this can be easily solved with at least viewaccess scoped bean.

EDIT: Now i noticed that exception is thrown in Process Validations phase, I initially thought that exception is thrown in Update Model Values phase. I changed "private User" to "private User user = new User()" and now it's OK, but it feels little weird.

Regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OmniFaces `<o:viewParam>` sets the request parameter only in the initial request and not in postbacks. This is intented to be used with `@ViewScoped` beans so that the request parameter isn't unnecessarily been validated, converted and updated on every single postback (because it's already still present in a view scoped bean). The [API documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/component/input/ViewParam.html) and the [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) also explicitly mentions that it should be used with view scoped beans.

You've there however a request scoped bean which get trashed and recreated on every single request, also on postbacks to the same view. So the `user` property disappears and falls back to default `null` on every subsequent postback request.

There are basically 2 ways to fix it:

1. Replace `<o:viewParam>` by `<f:viewParam>`. It will call the setter on every request, also on postbacks.
2. Replace `@Named @RequestScoped` by `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped`, this way the bean will live as long as you're interacting with the same view. Or if you insist in using CDI, use `@Named @ConversationScoped` instead, but you have to manage the begin and end of the conversation yourself.

Comment: Hi Bauke, I tested my code with with Mojarra 2.1.10 and MyFaces 2.1.8. In Mojarra, f:viewParam behaves as you described. In MyFaces, setter is not called on postback, so f:viewParam works like o:viewParam there. O:viewParam can then be used to circumvent compatibility issues. I would like to use request scoped beans as much as possible. I had an idea that in edit form I will store entity id in hidden field and in setId setter I will load that entity and other components will store their values in Update Model Values into newly loaded entity.

Comment: Problem is that Process Validations phase requires object for conversion to find out what Converter should be used. I solved my problem with initilization of user object in declaration of HomeBean class - this empty object is used for converter detection and in Update Modes Values this object is replaced with entity loaded from database.